# I wonder why this call to jquery on anchor tag is not working

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".order").click(function () {
            alert("ll");
        });
    });
</script>


<a class="order">helo</a>
```

I don't seem to find any error in this piece of code.
But it wont work or wont give any alert box.
Why is it so?

**EDIT**

Pete thanks the console showed $ not defined or referenced or something like that.

Actually i was doing this code in aspx page which was inheriting a masterpage.The master page included the jquery

I included the jquery in this vary page and it worked.

But still i am confused..isn't it supposed to work if the jquery is defined in the master page.

Comment: Yea in the master page `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Sorry, i deleted my comment since i did not see, you have no href tag. I've asked the OP, is he loaded the jQuery. So add `href="#"` to your `a` tag, and use `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: What's the error ? coz everybody would be having diff. implementation of ur code with diff ans kindly specify ! @Chelsea

Comment: do any errors show in your js console? (press f12 in your browser to get to your console)

Comment: If your console shows up no errors, then the alert is working. You just cannot see, because probably you disabled alerts. Change the alert to `console.info('ll');`

Comment: You have done a relative path to your js so if your page is from the root directory it will work, but if it is from a page like www.example.com/example/page, then it won't. try adding slash before the scripts: `/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js` or if it's an application then you may need to resolve `~/Scipts/jquery-1.9.0.js`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
<a class="order" href="javascript:void(0)">helo</a>

 $(".order").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("ll");
 });
```

Comment: shouldn't make any difference as the anchor hasn't got an href: http://jsfiddle.net/oLzvbu0y/

Comment: are you include the jquery header file?

Comment: yea but in the master page.i included the jquery in the same page including the abobe piece of code and now its working

Comment: href is the main attribute in a tag. it is must in a tag. If you didn't use href attribute in a tag please make it span.

Comment: @jQueryKing `href` is not mandatory for the [anchor tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html) - if it is omitted it is classed as a [placeholder hyperlink](http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tutorials/qt/html5-placeholder-links.htm)